# Use elem.send_keys for handle "Infinite Scroll" in page. Using Selenium PhantomJS in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, infinite-scroll

I need to take elements identified by xpath in a "Infinite Scroll" web page like [this](https://medium.com/top-100/december-2013). 
The problem is that when i use Selenium with webdriver PhantomJS it takes only some links, the first links loaded after the page is loaded.
I try to increase the *time.sleep()* or insert more of there in the code but not works. If i use Firefox like a webdriver it works well.

It's possibile sove this problem and improve my code?
Maybe not using time event but looking something that can tell if go down on the page or not.

Thanks and Greetings

```
import re
import mechanize
from pydblite import Base
from selenium import webdriver
import platform
import codecs
import scrapy  
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class getFrom(object):



def scrapying(self):
    print platform.system()


        #browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')



    browser.get("https://medium.com/top-100/december-2013")
    time.sleep(5)

    elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

    no_of_pagedowns = 200

    while no_of_pagedowns:
        elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.02)
        no_of_pagedowns-=1

    #Qui ci dovrebbe essere lo spider

    post_elems = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("graf--h2")

    #Fine Spider

    for post in post_elems:
        print post.text

    browser.quit()

myClassObject = getFrom()
myClassObject.scrapying()
```

Comment: I try to replace 
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.02)
In the while with browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") and setting time sleep at 0.2 because PhantomJs is more fast to loading the page then firefox.
With this solution works with phantomjs too.
But i have still dubit for the "elegance" of this type of method.
I'm waiting for some comparison or better code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my code like this:

```
import re
import mechanize
from pydblite import Base
from selenium import webdriver
import platform
import codecs
import scrapy
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class getFrom(object):



def scrapying(self):
    print platform.system()

    if platform.system()=="Windows":
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    else:
        #browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')



    browser.get("https://medium.com/top-100/december-2013")
    time.sleep(5)

    elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")


    mins = raw_input("For how many minutes you want to scrapy the links? ")

    print "start: "+ time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
    timeout = time.time() + 60* int(mins) # 5 minutes from now

    while True:
        test = 0
        elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
            print "end: "+ time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
            break
        test = test - 1

    #Qui ci dovrebbe essere lo spider

    post_elems = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("graf--h2")

    #Fine Spider

    for post in post_elems:
        print post.text

    browser.quit()



myClassObject = getFrom()
myClassObject.scrapying()
```

Now works fine.
I delete the for loop add a time control for handling the possibility of gain few results or a lots of then.
But the must important thing is use this javascript function:
            browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Instead of the send_keys